Constructing an $n$-simplex at the border of a $n$-ball by orthogonal hyperplanes
I want to construct an $n$-simplex the following way:

Choose $n$ vectors in the boundary of an $n$ dimensional ball, which are forming an $(n-1)$-simplex together.

Place the orthogonal affine $n-1$-hyperplane on each of these vectors.


My question now is: Does the part enclosed by these hyperplanes together with the $(n-1)$-simplex now form an $n$-simplex?

By "$n$-simplex" do you mean a regular $n$-simplex?

Yes. It comes out to the question whether those hyperplanes (given the circumstances) all intersect in one point, which becomes the $n+1$ vertex of the $n$-Simplex.
